# Configure Nginx server to work with a React app in a sub-folder of Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have a wordpress site hosting on Nginx server. I am trying to deploy my react app to run under the sub-folder of the wordpress site. I saw similar questions/answers and I tried following settings in my nginx config.

```
location /reactApp {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /reactApp/index.html;
}
```

It is a simple blog application and app's home page works, but the problem is - I also have to pass a URL parameter to the app to display the proper blog post.

```
http://www.example.com/reactApp/   <== works!    
http://www.example.com/reactApp/article-name <== Wwordpress 404 error
```

When I passed the "article-name", I got Wordpress's 404 error page.

My routing is as follows:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router basename={'reactApp'}>
    <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/:slug`} component={ReadArticle}/>
</Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

"slug" is the parameter I am trying to pass, in this case "article-name" is being passed.

In my package.json

```
"homepage": "http://www.example.com/reactApp/",
```

Please advise how to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show/attach the complete Nginx config?

Comment: Any updates on this?